# R - Perform Function on Matrix Values using Value Location

Tags: r, matrix, apply

I'm building a software that takes advantage of R's matrix calculations to build a heat map. Assuming I've got the following as my starting matrix:

```
        -1.8784 -1.8783 -1.8782
53.5919       0       0       0
53.592        0      50       0
53.5921       0       0       0
```

How would I transform it into the following?

```
        -1.8784 -1.8783 -1.8782
53.5919       0    12.5       0
53.592     12.5      25    12.5
53.5921       0    12.5       0
```

i.e. what I'm trying to do is reduce the value at a certain point by increasing the surrounding values to give a more steady gradient on the map.

I've tried utilising apply, but I can't seem to work out how to pass the location of the current index being worked on into the function. For loops are, obviously, an option but they're famously slow in R and I would quite like to have some level of optimisation to this.

Is there any more elegant solution than iterating through each value in the matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following may do what you want. It is certainly possible to it more elegantly I believe. But my linear algebra is too far away to do that off the top of my head though.

First, I construct some toy data.

Matrix to "smooth":

```
x <- 0*diag(10)  
x[8,4] <- x[6,7] <- x[3,3] <- 50
print(x)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [3,]    0    0   50    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0   50    0    0     0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [8,]    0    0    0   50    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

Next, we define a helper matrix that can be utilized in matrix-matrix multiplication:

```
b <- 0*diag(10)
b[col(b) == row(b) + 1] <- 0.5
b[col(b) == row(b) - 1] <- 0.5
print(b)  # A symmetric matrix with the first off-diagonal set to 0.5
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [2,]  0.5  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [3,]  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [4,]  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [5,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [6,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.0   0.0
 [7,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.5  0.0   0.0
 [8,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.5   0.0
 [9,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.0   0.5
[10,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5   0.0
```

Do the computation:

```
res <- x %*% b + b %*% x + x
res
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [2,]    0    0   25    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [3,]    0   25   50   25    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [4,]    0    0   25    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0   25    0    0     0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0   25   50   25    0     0
 [7,]    0    0    0   25    0    0   25    0    0     0
 [8,]    0    0   25   50   25    0    0    0    0     0
 [9,]    0    0    0   25    0    0    0    0    0     0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

**Edit** This yields the same:

```
d <- 0.5*diag(10)
d[col(d) == row(d) + 1] <- 0.5
d[col(d) == row(d) - 1] <- 0.5

res2 <- x %*% d + d %*% x  # or crossprod(d, x) + tcrossprod(x, d)
print(res2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't even consider doing matrix multiplication to get the result I wanted! I'll play around with the helper matrix and see if I can get a nice smooth gradient.

Comment: Glad I could help. You should probably also spend some time investigating the `Matrix` package. I guess representing them as a sparse matrices and utilizing that would bring down the computation time.